Mongoose callback query string isn't complete in hm->query.ptr
I'm using mongoose in a simple C webserver app, on ubuntu.
I point some curl at it like: curl http://127.0.0.1?Domain=Test&User=David
The callback is called OK, but the hm->query.ptr doesn't contain the whole query string.
It only contains Domain=Test  .
  static void cb(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data, void *fn_data) {
    struct mg_http_message *hm = (struct mg_http_message *)ev_data, tmp = {0};
    ...
    std::string query_text(hm->query.ptr, hm->query.len);
    std::cout << "Query=" << query_text << " length=" << hm->query.len << std::endl;

What happened to the remainder of the query string? And, how do I get it?

Have you tried http://127.0.0.1?Domain=Test&User=David ?

Ah, damn, typo. I did mean to use '&'. So, I will edit the original text and correct that. To be clear, it's not working when using your URL.

Have you looked at mg_http_parse()?

I can already get hold of the mg_http_message struct through the ev_data parameter in the callback: struct mg_http_message *hm = (struct mg_http_message *)ev_data, tmp = {0};

Oh, I think it's a problem because I'm using curl to send the data!!! If I use the URL in a browser address bar then the mongoose webserver receives both parts of the query string and processes it properly. So, curl is my problem.

Probably best to include your command as formatted code block. That way someone could have detected the missing string quotes. Glad you solved it.

I worked it out.
The problem is the & character is being interpreted by the shell as the end of the command putting the command in to the background.
I need to add quotes around the URL, like this:
curl "http://127.0.0.1?Domain=Test&User=David"
